# How to get a row rank?

Tags: mysql, rank

HI,

I actually posted similar (or same?) question yesterday, but I thought I need to post a new question since I have short, but clear question.

I have the following table.

```
id  point
1   30
2   30
3   29
4   27
5   28
6   26
```

what I want:

1. get all the users order by rank. user #1 and #2 should have 1 as their rank value because they both have 30 points
2. I want to query a rank by user id. I like to get 1 as the result of my rank when I query user #1 and #2 because both of them have 30 points

**Added on: 3/18**

I tried Logan's query, but got the following result

```
id point   rank
1   30  1
2   30  1
3   29  3
4   27  5
5   28  4
6   26  6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subquery approach that you have seen recommended will scale quadratically.  http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/ shows a much more efficient approach with user variables.  Here is an untested adaptation to your problem:

```
@points := -1; // Should be an impossible value.
@num := 0;

SELECT id
  , points
  , @num := if(@points = points, @num, @num + 1) as point_rank
  , @points := points as dummy
FROM `users`
ORDER BY points desc, id asc;
```

Comment: I tried to add where statment to query a specified row, but I always get 1 as point_rank. below is my query

Comment: SELECT 
    *, 
    vote_ratio ,
     @num := if( @vote_ratio = vote_ratio, @num , @num +1 ) AS rank
   FROM challenge_photos
   where img_status = 1 and img_id = 65 ORDER BY vote_ratio DESC";

Comment: @btilly //forgot mention your id.

Comment: @Moon: What you need to do is make what I wrote into a view, and then select from the view.  If you need to access the view repeatedly, save it into a table (which can be temporary if you want) and then access that.

Comment: @btilly // thanks again!! but the problem is...it would be a high traffic website. I don't think it is a good idea to query all the records and make a view every time someone click a photo to see its rank..

Comment: @Moon: In that case store a table that precalculates the result, and refresh it regularly with a cron.

Comment: The first two users are supposed to have the same rank. The num + 1 actually needs to be incremented like num + number_of_ranks_skipped. See my solution...

Answer (score 5):

Just count how many people have more points then them.

```
select count(1) from users 
where point > (select point from users where id = 2) group by point
```

This will give you the number of people that have more points for the given user.  So for user 1 and user 2 the result will be 0 (zero) meaning they are first.

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to do something similar, I created a view that looked like this:

```
CREATE VIEW rankings_view 
AS 
SELECT id
,      point
,      (select count(1) 
          from points b
         where  b.point > a.point) +1 as rank
FROM points as a;
```

This assumes that the original table was named points, obviously. Then you can get the rank of any id, or the id corresponding to any rank, by querying the view.

EDIT

If you want to count the number of distinct point values above each point value instead of the number of entries with point values above the current point value, you can do something like:

```
CREATE VIEW rankings_view2
AS 
SELECT id
,      point
,      (SELECT COUNT(1) +1 AS rank 
          FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT point
                   FROM points b
                  WHERE   b.point >a.point ))
FROM points AS a;
```

NOTE

Some of the other solutions presented definitely perform better than this one. They're mysql specific, so I can't really use them for what I'm doing.  My application has, at most, 128 entities to rank, so this works well enough for me. If you might have tons of rows, though, you might want to look at using one of the other solutions presented here or limiting the scope of the ranking.

Comment: why create the view? The select statement works (though I'd add `ORDER BY rank ASC`). Nice solution.

Comment: @Dawson I like to keep most of my SQL in the database itself in views and stored procedures.

Comment: @Logan // added the query result above

Comment: @Logan // is it possible to get the value 2 for id #2 instead of 3? I know that 3 makes sense since there are two rank #1, but I just wonder if I can set it as #2 instead of #3.

Comment: @Moon  That shouldn't be a problem. You need to count the number of distinct point values above each point value instead of the number of rows. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Logan // wow...I appreciate your answer! it works perfectly now.

Comment: With duplicate rows i get: `View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause`

Answer (score 2):

The OP would like to have rank numbers skipped if their previously were duplicate points with the same rank. E.g. below see how 2 is skipped because rank 1 appears twice.

```
id  point  rank
1   30     1
2   30     1
3   29     3
4   27     4
5   28     5
6   26     6
```

This can be achieved by modifying btilly's code as follows:

```
set @points := -1; // Should be an impossible value.
set @num := 0;
set @c := 1;
SELECT id
  , points
  , @num := if(@points = points, @num, @num + @c) as point_rank
  , @c := if(@points = points, @c+1, 1) as dummy
  , @points := points as dummy2
FROM `users`
ORDER BY points desc, id asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8 you can use [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) like:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  score,
  rank() over (order by amount) as ranking
FROM
  SomeTable
```

If you need to select **only one** row, use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT
  id
  score,
  ranking
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    score,
    rank() over (order by score) as ranking
  FROM
    SomeTable
) t
WHERE
  id = ?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET @rank = 0, @prev_val = NULL;
SELECT id, @rank := IF(@prev_val=points,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank,
@prev_val := points AS points FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, id asc;
```

Table:users

Comment: The first two users are supposed to have the same rank.

Comment: Yep. Sorry about that. Thanks for the lashing. Answer revamped

Comment: When revamping your answer, you *could* have acknowledged that it is the same idea as the answer I posted before you revamped yours.

Comment: Sorry. It really was an oversight. My solution: tested, and verified to OP. I think I like @Logan's better any way. It's more direct, and easier to read - it's simpler.

Comment: @Dawson: It is true that @Logan has a simpler solution.  But if you have 100,000 rows in your table, performance will kill you.

Comment: @btilly - indeed. Kind of a crux with the forum. You never know how involved to make an answer based on a lot of the posts. The OP may just have a 100 row table, or this is a homework assignment on syntax/technique.