# How can I optimize my query (rank query)?

Tags: mysql, subquery, rank

For the last two days, I have been asking questions on rank queries in Mysql. So far, I have working queries for

1. query all the rows from a table and order by their rank.
2. query ONLY one row with its rank

Here is a link for my question from last night

[How to get a row rank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347565/how-to-get-a-row-rank)

As you might notice, btilly's query is pretty fast.

Here is a query for getting ONLY one row with its rank that I made based on btilly's query.

```
set @points = -1; 
set @num = 0;

select * from (

SELECT id
  , points
  , @num := if(@points = points, @num, @num + 1) as point_rank
  , @points := points as dummy
FROM points
ORDER BY points desc, id asc

) as test where test.id = 3
```

the above query is using subquery..so..I am worrying about the performance.

are there any other faster queries that I can use?

**Table points**

```
id      points
1   50
2   50
3   40
4   30
5   30
6   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get into a panic about subqueries. Subqueries aren't *always* slow - only in some situations. The problem with your query is that it requires a *full scan*.

Here's an alternative that should be faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT points) + 1
FROM points
WHERE points > (SELECT points FROM points WHERE id = 3)
```

Add an index on `id` (I'm guessing that you probably you want a primary key here) and another index on `points` to make this query perform efficiently.

Comment: // Thank you for the input. I just added a sample table with 6 rows. Your query works fine for id #1,2, but I get a different result with id #3. I am expecting 2 as the result, but I get 3. How do I get 2 instead of 3 for id #3? I am getting 3 because there are two records (#1 and #2) that have higher values than #3.

Comment: @Moon: To fix that change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT points)`. See update.

Comment: // Finally!!! I really appreciate your help!!!! Have a great weekend! (I will with your help!!)

Comment: GREAT JOB! Your solution for what I'm doing is taking 0.053s compared to 1.652s using mariadb's row_number() window function