# MYSQL get row rank

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table and I need to get random row and get the rank of total view

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| id     | name       |totalview|
+--------+------------+---------+
| 1      | ex1        |   20    |
| 2      | ex2        |   100   |
| 3      | ex3        |   30    |
| 4      | ex4        |   40    |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

for example :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$rand';
```

`$rand` may be 1 or 2 etc ..

I need to get rank of this row by totalview

thank's

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a row rank?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347565/how-to-get-a-row-rank)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t2 WHERE totalview > t1.totalview ) + 1 cnt
  FROM table t1
 WHERE id = '$rand';
```

Comment: @Arvind Bhardwaj: it depends on how you would like to resolve rank in case of ties. It might be acceptable in one cases, and may be wrong in others. So it's task dependent but not absolute wrong solution.

Comment: Thats right. Do we have a solution that works in case of ties?

Comment: @Arvind Bhardwaj: it **does work** in case of ties. There is no single way to calculate a rank for ties case and it depends on the task. If it doesn't work for your case - you need to explain your particular case (in a separate question)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(ref.totalview < t.totalview) FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t1 ref WHERE t1.id = '$rand'
```